# Trying to webscrape the price from an Amazon page using the CSS selector and Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to learn about web-scraping in the Udemy course 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'.

I'm trying to use Python along with the requests and BeautifulSoup modules, and the CSS selector to return the price of a given Amazon item.

I can see in the course that a number of people can't get this to work, so I suspect something has changed about the Amazon webpage. However, I've also tried on some other webpages e.g. currys.co.uk and can't seem to get it to work there either.

BeautifulSoup seems to parse everything just fine, I don't think the problem is there, it's just when I tried to get the CSS selector from Chrome that things don't work.

For example, on this webpage:

[https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275994)

if I rightclick on the price, click on 'Inspect', then Copy->Copy Selector, I get

```
#unqualifiedBuyBox > div > div.a-text-center.a-spacing-mini > span
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the CSS selector that I'm looking for, and putting it into my Python code doesn't return the price.

Am I doing something completely wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: many pages use JavaScript to add elements to page but `BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript - so often it can't get elements. And then you may need Selenium to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you may try to use `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab: Network, filter: XHR) to find url used by JavaScript to read data and then you can use `requests` to get data from this url - often you get data in JSON format so you don't need `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: BTW: turn off JavaScript in web browser and reload page to see what `BeautifulSoup` can get from server.

Comment: some servers send different HTML for different devices - phone, tablet, desktop - so it can be important to use correct header `User-Agent`. Other servers can recognize that you run script and send page with warning and block you - so you could save HTML to page and display in web browser to see what you get.

Comment: Other than the fact that amazon wants to block crawlers, you're missing the `#` symbol.
Try this on chrome console:

    `$("#unqualifiedBuyBox > div > div.a-text-center.a-spacing-mini > span").innerText`

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh OP already had `#` in CSS selector but OP incorrectly formated text in question and Stackoverflow used `#` to display it as bold text :)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your code, but here are a few possible issues I had to troubleshoot while working on this problem myself:

**1. Your request is triggering Amazon's CAPTCHA**

You can confirm this after parsing the page with BeautifulSoup by taking a look at your soup:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

If Amazon has detected the scraper, the resulting file will only be a few hundred lines (CAPTCHA page) rather than 10,000+ lines (product page). To get around it, you can set your `User-Agent` and `Accept-Language` in the request header. Example:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_0_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US'
    }
res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/1593275994', headers=headers)
```

You can grab a user-agent profile that matches your environment [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome); for the accept-language it's best to keep it consistent with your IP address to avoid detection of bot-like behavior. You can see the full list from the [IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry).

**2. Chrome's Copy CSS path functionality has changed since the Udemy video was recorded**

`Copy CSS path` has now become `Copy selector`. To access it, right click on the element in [Elements Window > Copy > Copy selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gibai.png).

**3. The CSS path for the element varies by product availability**

The page styling for how Amazon displays the product price can vary depending on whether the item is available new or used, and whether the item is being fulfilled directly by Amazon or only available through Amazon Marketplace.

As of this writing, the correct CSS selector for the product link you shared is `#unqualified-buybox-olp > div > span` so you would use

```
elems = soup.select('#unqualified-buybox-olp > div > span')
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: 2021.07.29**

It seems example page changed structure and class `#unqualifiedBuyBox` doesn't exist.

---

**Original Anser:**

To get data I need two things:

1. headers `User-Agent`, `Accept-Language` to get HTML with data instead of message for bots/scripts
2. use parser `lxml` instead of `html.parser` to find elements (parsers work in different way)

But even this may not work if you will run code many times with short delays.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
#    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
#    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')

all_items = soup.select('#unqualifiedBuyBox > div > div.a-text-center.a-spacing-mini > span')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```

---

**EDIT: 2021.07.29**

Original answer is one year old and now example page doesn't have price and other pages use different classes and ids - so now it needs different selector.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
#    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
#    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}

#url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994'
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#soup = BS(r.text, 'html.parser')
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')

all_items = soup.select('#newBuyBoxPrice')
for item in all_items:
    print(item.text)
```